# Matrix operations to flip 3d models front to back, without changing position

Tags: opengl, matrix

Multiple 3D objects look to be in the correct screen position, and I can move around them and this continues to be true, but each one looks like it is flipped back to front (I can see the backside of the object as if the camera were on the other side of it).

Any clues to why this may be happening in addition to correcting it would be welcome also- I'm getting a transform matrix from one api what is documented as OpenGL 4x4 matrix format, but my underlying api (bgfx) is wrapping opengl so may be assuming another format.  I can probably go get the transform in different format, but now I'd really like to know how to correct this also if there was no option but to start with the opengl matrix.

Comment: Without seeing actual code, we can't determine the source of the problem. Maybe your models are backwards

Comment: The code is here https://github.com/lucasw/bgfx_ros/blob/master/src/bgfx_ros.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a wrong face culling mode, change either to

BGFX_STATE_CULL_CW

or to

BGFX_STATE_CULL_CCW

using

bgfx::setState

Comment: I didn't realize I had `BGFX_STATE_CULL_CW` set through `BGFX_STATE_DEFAULT`, or that my triangles were in fact clockwise.